# Checkbox as a Link in ASP.net MVC 4 or 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

Is possible to make a checkbox as a link with parameter that refer to the controller's AcionResult in ASP.net MVC 4 or 5?

Comment: May be you can do it with JavaScript, but please provide more information what you are trying to do and share some code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by make custom html helper.
in custom helper you make any thing you want

example:

```
       public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxLabelFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> pHtml, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> pExpression, IDictionary<string, Object> pLabelHtmlAttributes, string pCaption)
    {
        try
        {
            MvcHtmlString tCheckBox;
            string tCheckBoxWithLabel;
            TagBuilder tBuilder;

            tCheckBox = InputExtensions.CheckBoxFor(pHtml, pExpression);
            tBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
            tBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(pLabelHtmlAttributes));

            tCheckBoxWithLabel ="<a>" + tBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag) + tCheckBox.ToString() + pCaption + "</label></a>";

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tCheckBoxWithLabel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsINFEventLogger.LogEvent(mdlEnumerations.INFEventTypes.Error, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

this code make check box with label as link, now to use it and redirect the link to action controller you must use it on your view like this:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxLabelFor(model => model.Test,new Dictionary<string, object> {  { "onclick", "location.href= '" + @Url.Action(YourController, YourAction, Model) + "'" } }, "Test Caption")
```

your html generated will seem like this:

```
<a><label onclick="location.href= '/Namespace/YourController/YourAction'"><input id="Test" name="Test" type="checkbox" value="true">Test</label></a>
```

you can edit your custom helper as you want to do what you want :)